# Handling events using UseState in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I created 3 components: App, UserList & UserInfo. 
When I click on the button (get Users) I receive a list of users, how can I get user information when I click on each user in the list?

I read about event handling but I don't know how to apply it in this example.

**App.js**

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import UserList from './components/UserList'
import UserInfo from './components/UserInfo'

function App() {
  const [users, setUsers] = useState([])


 async function getUsers(){
    try{
      const response = await fetch(`https://randomuser.me/api/?results=5`)
      if(!response.ok){
        throw Error('something went wrong during fetch API')
      }

      const data = await response.json()
      setUsers(data.results)
      console.log(data)

    } catch (error){
      console.log(error)

    }
  }


  return (
    <div className="App">

     <button onClick={()=> getUsers()}>Get Users</button>
     <UserList users={users}/>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

**UserList.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import uuid from 'uuid'

const UserList = ({users, onClickUser}) => {
    return (
        <div>
            <ul>
                {
                    users.map(user =>{
                        return(
                    <li key={uuid()} onClick={() => onClickUser(user) }>{user.name.first}</li>
                    ) 
                })}
            </ul>
        </div>
    );
};

export default UserList;
```

**UserInfo.js**

```
import React from "react";

const UserInfo = ({ information }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        {information.name.first} {information.name.last}
      </div>
      <div>{information.email}</div>
      <div>{information.gender}</div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default UserInfo;
```

Comment: You are not passing your event handler to UserList component.

Comment: Could you please show me how can I do that? I'm new to react and still don't understand it well enough

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are extremely close to getting this working... Only that you are not using the `onClickUser` prop within your `App` component (aka you aren't passing it down).. Here is an example of how you can accomplish what you're after:

```js
const { useState } = React;
const { render } = ReactDOM;

const UserList = ({ users, onClickUser }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <ul>
        {users.map(user => {
          return (
            <li key={uuid()} onClick={() => onClickUser(user)} style={{cursor: 'pointer'}}>
              {user.name.first}
            </li>
          );
        })}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
};

const UserInfo = ({ information }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        {information.name.first} {information.name.last}
      </div>
      <div>{information.email}</div>
      <div>{information.gender}</div>
    </div>
  );
};

function App() {
  const [users, setUsers] = useState([]);
  const [clickedUser, setClickedUser] = useState("");

  async function getUsers() {
    try {
      const response = await fetch(`https://randomuser.me/api/?results=5`);
      if (!response.ok) {
        throw Error("something went wrong during fetch API");
      }

      const data = await response.json();
      setUsers(data.results);
      console.log(data);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  }

  const handleUserClick = user => {
    console.log(user);
    setClickedUser(user);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button onClick={() => getUsers()}>Get Users</button>
      {users.length ? <p style={{marginBottom: '0px'}}>Click on a user to see user info</p> : ""}
      {/* THIS IS WHAT YOU HAD BEFORE: */}
      {/* <UserList users={users} /> */}
      <UserList users={users} onClickUser={handleUserClick} />
      {clickedUser ? <pre>{JSON.stringify(clickedUser, null, 2)}</pre> : ""}
    </div>
  );
}

function uuid() { // only here so this doesn't bomb out
  return "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-4xxx-yxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx".replace(/[xy]/g, function(c) {
    var r = (Math.random() * 16) | 0,
      v = c == "x" ? r : (r & 0x3) | 0x8;
    return v.toString(16);
  });
}

render(<App />, document.body);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.12.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.11.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-standalone/6.26.0/babel.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Matt, that was very useful